# Making a button display different texts in a label Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm new to Javafx and I'm trying to make a single button display my stored strings in an arrayList.The code works fine but only displays once and no matter how many times click it never changes.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController  {
    public Label lblNext;
    public Button btnNext;
    int count = 0;

    public void btnClick(){
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("one");
        words.add("two");
        words.add("three");
        words.add("four");
        count=+1;
        lblNext.setText(""+words.get(count));   
    }
}
```

Below is the FXML code .

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="321.0" prefWidth="412.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="memorizer.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>

        <Label fx:id="lblNext" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="13.0" ``layoutY="10.0"         minHeight="16" minWidth="69" prefHeight="244.0" prefWidth="386.0" text="Click     Next To Begin" />

        <Button fx:id="btnNext" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="265.0" mnemonicParsing="true" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="113.0" text="Next" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
count += 1;
```

or something similar instead of

```
count=+1;
```

which is equivalent to

```
count=1;
```

i.e. it always assigns the same value to `count` which means the index read from is always the same and the text therefore never changes...

Note that starting with the 4th click the event handler will start causing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s...

---

Also if you increment the value before reading the element from the list, you'll start with the second instead of the first element. You may want to swap the statements:

```
lblNext.setText(words.get(count));
count++; // shortened version of count+=1;
```

---

Also the ``` `` ``` part inside the fxml means the file is not a well-formed xml file and therefore must be removed for the file to be parsed properly...

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out,my method was missing an action event.

public void btnClick(ActionEvent event);

Comment: That makes no difference